# Execute sudo using expect inside ssh from bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I want to create a script that automates a installation on multiple linux hosts.
I login to the hosts using ssh keys and inside the login I want to do a sudo, I am trying to use expect, which I have on the stations but **I don't have on the server** which runs the script.
How do I do this, this is my try, but no luck with it:

```
#!/bin/bash


ssh user@station04 <<EOF
expect -d -c "
send \"sudo ls\"
expect {
        \"password:\" { send '1234'; exp_continue }
        \"$user@\"{
                send "exit\r"
        }
        default {exit 1}
}"
EOF


exit
```

The result:

```
send: sending "sudo ls" to { exp0 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "password:"? no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp0"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = -c  argv[3] = 
send "sudo ls\r"
expect {
    "password:" { send '1234';  exp_continue }
    "@"{
        send exitr
    }
    default {exit 1}
}  
set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
```

Comment: Do you have control over `/etc/sudoers` on these systems? If so, the strongly preferable approach is to modify that file and specify that `ls` (or whatever else you're running) can be invoked by `user` with no password. That way you're not embedding plaintext passwords in code and risking them getting stolen.

Comment: No, I don't have control over sudoers. I'll remove the password from the script after I'm done with it

Comment: Do you have a description of how this fails, beyond "no luck"? Is there any message given (for instance, a complaint about lack of a tty)?

Answer (score 0):

A.K

What about this?  <- just make sure of the expected prompts.

```
#!/bin/bash

expect <<'END'
spawn ssh user@station04
expect "password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "#"
send "sudo ls\r"

END
```

Comment: I don't have expect on the server

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you would use public key authentication for the ssh part, then just use something like:

```
ssh -t username@server-ip -C "echo sudo-password | /usr/bin/sudo -S ls"
```

Comment: how about rsync a script first and then running it using sudo with the command above?

Comment: Why don't you copy a full script to the destination, then run it, then remove it !.

Comment: anyway, the problem is with sudo, because I don't want to copy to 15 stations, I want to execute it only once

Answer (score 0):

You got the usage of `expect` not quite right - don't `send` a command; rather `spawn` the command and `send` just its input. So, your script becomes:

```
ssh … <<EOF
expect -d -c "
    spawn sudo ls
    expect -nocase password: { send 1234\r }
    expect eof
"
exit
EOF
```